# annnotation crash octave while print

Tags: octave

Octave crashes without error when i`ll call print(image successfully saving) 
for next code

```
graphics_toolkit('fltk'); 
h=figure('renderer', 'opengl','renderermode', 'manual', 'color', 'white',... 
'inverthardcopy', 'off','units', 'inches','paperunits', 
'inches','paperorientation', 'portrait',... 
'visible', 'on','name', 'amplitudeImage','defaulttextcolor', 
'black','position', [1 1 7 8.5],... 
'paperposition', [0.5 0.5 7 8.5],'numbertitle', 'off'); 

ofst=0.215; 
h=axes('units', 'inches', 'position', [0 0 7 8.5], 'Visible', 'off'); 
annotation('line',[0.01 0.01],[0.7168 0.915]-ofst,'color',[0.0 0.0 
0.0],'linewidth',1)% bottom bar 
annotation('line',[0.008 0.012],[0.7168 .7168]-ofst,'color',[0.0 0.0 
0.0],'linewidth',1)% bottom bar 
annotation('line',[0.006 0.014],[0.8159 0.8159]-ofst,'color',[0.0 0.0 
0.0],'linewidth',1)% bottom bar 
annotation('line',[0.008 0.012],[0.915 0.915]-ofst,'color',[0.0 0.0 
0.0],'linewidth',1)% bottom bar 
print mypng.jpg
```

I tried change graphics toolkit,  units type for axes but it did not helps. 
But all right if I am not using annotation. 
What can I replace annotation?

Octave v5.1.0, Windows 10.

Comment: Maybe something to submit as a bug report to the Octave bug tracker?

Comment: Please file a bugreport in Savannah. Can you try to strip down your code to a bare minimum needed to trigger the problem? Btw, what is the reason to usw the fltk interface and habe you tried the default qt?